# Get Maven Version in an AWS Lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, aws-lambda

I am developing an AWS Lambdas using java.  It would be very useful if, in the lambda, there was a way to log the maven version of the lambda in the log file so we can track what versions of lambdas are running in different environments.  Normally this could be done pretty easily using the code below:

```
    String version = null;
    try {
        Properties p = new Properties();
        InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/maven/com.my.example/my-lambda/pom.properties");
        if (is != null) {
            p.load(is);
            version = p.getProperty("version", "");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ignore
    }
    log.info(version);
    Package aPackage = getClass().getPackage();
    if(aPackage != null){
        version = aPackage.getImplementationVersion();
        if(version == null){
            version = aPackage.getSpecificationVersion();
        }
    }
    log.info(version);
```

Unfortunately it always comes up null for the version.  I verified that the jar file has the specified path and the pom.properties is present in the jar in the correct path with the version information contained within.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:  The answer has to be specific to running the java jar as an aws lambda.  Getting it out of a jar is normally pretty trivial using the code above, but when the jar is run as an aws lambda it doesn't seem to be able to access the various the maven files to get the version information.

NOTE on the answer:  AWS sam build takes the built jars and deploys only certain files to be available to the lambda.  You can see this when you run your lambda in an IDE and the aws-toolkit creates the .aws-sam/build folder.  Unlike in typical jars, only the lambda class file and any resources defined in the pom.xml with the resources tag are copied here.  I used the suggestion to use the git-commit-id-plugin to create a git.properties file with version information, which is created in the root of the project.  To make it so aws knows to copy this file also, you need to modify the pom.xml to include the git.properties file as shown below:

```
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>./</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/git.properties</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
```

Comment: What does "the maven version of the lambda" mean?  There is the version of the jar you deployed to Lambda *after* you've used maven to build the jar.  Maven is not used inside of Lambda.

Comment: Yes, the maven version of the jar file.  The jar file is built using maven and deployed as an aws lambda.  I want to be able to get the version of the jar when it is run as an aws lambda.

Comment: That's not the maven version, like `3.6.3`, that's the version of your code.  You're mixing two things.  What source code management do you use (i.e. git, etc)?

Comment: You are correct. The version of the artifact (ie the jar file), not the version of maven used to build the artifact.

Comment: The reason we want to get the artifact version is so we can log it and testers can look in CloudWatch to see what version of the code they are testing against when they encounter defects or questions.  This is normally simple when running as a jar or in spring, but for some reason it seems to be a challenge when running it as a java aws lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* you use Git, I do the following.  In my `pom.xml` I have (in the `build/plugins` section):

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>revision</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <configuration>
                <useNativeGit>true</useNativeGit>
                <dateFormat>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX</dateFormat>
                <dotGitDirectory>${project.basedir}/.git</dotGitDirectory>
                <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
                <failOnNoGitDirectory>false</failOnNoGitDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

In my Java code I have:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class VersionInfo {
    public static String getVersionString() {
        try {
            Properties properties = getGitProperties();

            boolean isDirty = false;

            String gitDirty = properties.getProperty( "git.dirty" );
            if( gitDirty != null )
                isDirty = Boolean.parseBoolean(gitDirty);

            return "built \"" + properties.getProperty("git.build.time") +
                    "\" in branch \"" + properties.getProperty("git.branch") +
                    "\" with short commit id \"" + properties.getProperty("git.commit.id.describe-short") + "\"" +
                    ", isDirty is " + isDirty +
                    " remote url is \"" + properties.getProperty("git.remote.origin.url") + "\"";
        }
        catch( IOException ioe ) {
            return( "can't locate git.properties on the class path");
        }
    }


    private static Properties getGitProperties() throws IOException {

        Properties properties = new Properties();

        try (InputStream inputStream = VersionInfo.class.getResourceAsStream("/git.properties")) {
            if (inputStream == null)
                throw new IOException("Can't locate properties file to generate version info");

            properties.load(inputStream);

            return properties;
        }
    }
}
```

And in my Lambda I have:

```
public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) {
    context.getLogger().log( "starting " + this.getClass().getName() + " version " + VersionInfo.getVersionString() );
}
```

Obviously you can get whatever information from the `git-properties` file.  It looks something like:

```
Generated by Git-Commit-Id-Plugin
#Mon Mar 22 10:15:05 MDT 2021
git.branch=develop
git.build.host=bluerock
git.build.time=2021-03-22T10\:16\:05-06\:00
git.build.user.email=
git.build.user.name=
git.build.version=1.1.0-SNAPSHOT
git.closest.tag.commit.count=
git.closest.tag.name=
git.commit.id=7745a4c46484b26c3285362e6f7526f551a9a60f
git.commit.id.abbrev=7745a4c
git.commit.id.describe=7745a4c
git.commit.id.describe-short=7745a4c
git.commit.message.full=some uber fixes
git.commit.message.short=some uber fixes
git.commit.time=2020-03-23T15\:16\:42-06\:00
git.commit.user.email=user@example.com
git.commit.user.name=User Name
git.dirty=false
git.remote.origin.url=https\://oauth2@git.example.com/some-project.git
git.tags=
git.total.commit.count=14
```

Comment: This is what I need!  I have one issue though.  The git.properties file is created.  I can see that it is in the root of the jar file even.  When I run the lambda in intellij the aws toolkit it doesn't copy the git.properties.  The aws toolkit, by default, creates the /.aws-sam/build directory.  It doesn't pull in the git.properties.  Any idea what is in your pom.xml to let the sam build know to pull in the git.properties?

Comment: To get this to work you also need one other maven piece to make sure the git.properties is included and copied correctly by aws sam build.  The aws sam build only includes resources set by the resource tag be availabe from within the lambda.  I had my git.properties created in the same folder as my template.yaml.  With this I had to add the following lines to my pom.xml:
```
            <resource>
                <directory>./</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/git.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
```

Comment: I wasn't using SAM for this - that is great information to add @AdamDewing

Comment: I wasn't using SAM directly, but the aws-toolkit, used in Intellij or Eclipse, to run lambdas in the IDE.  The aws-toolkit uses SAM commands it in the background.  You are a life saver btw :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try following to get the MAVEN Version:

```
import org.apache.maven.model.Model;
import org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader;
import org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class GetMAVENInfo {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    MavenXpp3Reader reader = new MavenXpp3Reader();
    Model model;
    if ((new File("pom.xml")).exists())
      model = reader.read(new FileReader("pom.xml"));
    else
      model = reader.read(
        new InputStreamReader(
          GetMAVENInfo.class.getResourceAsStream(
            "/META-INF/maven/GetMAVENInfo/pom.xml"
          )
        )
      );
    System.out.println(model.getId());
    System.out.println(model.getGroupId());
    System.out.println(model.getArtifactId());
    System.out.println(model.getVersion());
  }
}
```

OR You can try to following
`getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion()`

Comment: This would work when running a normal java JAR, except this jar is running as an aws lambda.  When you deploy the aws lambda it doesn't seem to be able to find the pom.xml or pom.properties using the above code, like you would normally, so it cannot find the pom.xml in the if or the else statement listed above.  The jars I have all work perfectly fine and actually do contain the above mentioned files.